# Find the Parts of speech

Tags: parts-of-speech

What are the parts of speech for the bold words in the following four sentences and why:

1. The after **effects** of the drug are bad.
2. He told us all **about** the battle.
3. He kept the **fast** for a week.
4. Sit down and rest a **while**.

My answers to three of the questions are as follows:
For 2 - about is a adjective
For 3 - fast is adverb
For 4 - while is adverb

Comment: Hi Rise!  "after-effect" is hyphenated. A dictionary will tell you what part of speech it is. [Here](https://www.lexico.com/definition/after-effect)'s one.

Comment: Thanks Old Brixtonian, any idea about the other 3?

Comment: How did you come up with your answers @Rise?  "Fast" is often an adverb (and often an adjective), but the context of the sentence "He kept the fast" makes clear it can only be a noun.  Did you understand the sentence, or did you try to apply a part of speech without knowing what the sentence meant?  Regardless, only a noun can fit in that position (cf "He kept the computer", "He kept the house", "He kept the phone") so "fast" must be a noun there.  Look at the structure of the phrase and the answers will often become clear. "He kept the slowly" would be ungrammatical, for example.

Comment: Thanks rjpond. For 3 - I now get it looking at the structure does make it a noun. Your examples illustrate how it can only be noun. I thought of it as adverb based on the idea that "kept" is the verb and "fast" is adding to it.

Answer (score 1):

> **What are the parts of speech for the bold words in the following four sentences and why:**

> A. The after **effects** of the drug are bad.

> B. He told us all **about** the battle.

> C. He kept the **fast** for a week.

> D. Sit down and rest a **while**.

---

> A. The after **effects** of the drug are bad. **Noun**

after effects is hyphenated and forms a noun.

**A noun is a word that represents a person, place, or thing.**

Ref CED [after-effect](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/aftereffect?q=after-effects)

---

> B. He told us all **about** the battle. **Preposition**

**"about" preposition** (CONNECTED WITH); a film about the Spanish Civil War. Ref CED **[**about**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/about)**

**A preposition is a word that usually tells where or when something is in relation to something else.**

---

> C. He kept the **fast** for a week. **Noun**

**"The" definite article We use the definite article in front of a noun**

**"fast"; noun**; a period of time when you eat no food: Ref CED [**fast**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fast?q=fasting)

However to me this sentence does not sound correct. But that was not the question.

---

> D. Sit down and rest a **while**. **NOUN**

**while; noun**; a length of time: Ref CED [**WHILE**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/while)